# rails app moving to new server; cannot serve app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Both servers are CentOS 5.4 with MySQL, Ruby, Rails, Phusion Passenger and Apache. I simply tar'd the original app as it sat in /var/www and untar'd it on the new server at the same loc. I ran

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

restarted httpd but cannot get anything but the default apache page.

I have a vhosts conf:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/tutorials.conf
```

that matches the original and I edited my httpd.conf appropriately.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? Is there a step-by-step out there for this particular scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SElinux was stopping it. Setenforce 0 and service httpd restart proved that.